# How to build a two-dimensional array pyramid

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I need to write a method that builds a 2d array - pyramid using numbers from 1 to n.

```
 int[][]  build(int n)
```

But i have no idea what algorithm can help me with it. Can anybody help me with how to predict array size from n?

Example : build(6) returns

```
            {{0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
            {0, 2, 0, 3, 0},
            {4, 0, 5, 0, 6}}
```

Comment: Where did those numbers come from? What is your question to be exact?

Comment: @user7 edited question

Comment: You should think about the problem for a couple of hours before asking for help, try some things out, write the code without loop for n=2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 and try to see a pattern, etc. And right now the it unclear what the output is supposed to represent, what should the thing e.g. return for n=5?

Comment: @luk2302 for n = 5 there will be an exception, because pyramid not exists for that n

Comment: See, one more information you failed to include in the original question. This will keep on happening until you state clearly what the input + outputs are. Have you already coded for a couple of hours trying out what might work and what does not? For example: can you tell me how wide the array is going to be for a given n?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good first step might be to see how many rows the array needs based on a given N. Once you have found that it should be a relatively simple matter to get the number of columns and fill them in accordingly.

So let's plot the relationship between Rows and N on a graph as X and Y. You can draw it or visualize it in your head: (1,1), (2,3), (3,6), etc...

As you can see this is not linear, and it appears to be parabolic. So you can do a little algebra or use a program to calculate the parabola for you:
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parabola+(1,1),(2,3),(3,6)

[image]

To confirm that the equation works, test with X=4 and X=5, and yes it works. `Y = 0.5X^2 + 0.5X`

Hopefully this should give you a start that enables you to solve the rest of the assignment.